# Load fetch_lfw_people using Proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, scikit-learn, dataset, jupyter-notebook

I want to use this toy dataset for education.
But when I try to load it using builtin sklearn loader I got the error.

```
from sklearn import datasets 
lfw_people = datasets.fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=50, 
                resize=0.4, data_home='.', )
```

Error:

> urlopen error [WinError 10061]

I know it is about the proxy - usually to install new packages I use --proxy option.
But how to do it now? There is no such option in `datasets.fetch_lfw_people`

---

I thought about manual downloading it from the official website: http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/#download
But I don't know which one to choose and how to open after that in python.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch_lfw_people` will by default check the data in `'~/scikit_learn_data/lfw_home'` to see if the dataset is already downloaded and correct or not (by matching hashes).

According to [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55bf5d9/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py#L243), it downloads 4 files from the following urls:

- For targets

  - **pairsDevTrain.txt**:   https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976012
  - **pairsDevTest.txt**:    https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976009
  - **pairs.txt**:           https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976006
- For data

  - **lfw-funneled.tgz** (Default):    https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976015

    OR
  - **lfw.tgz** (when `funneled=False`):    https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976018

So you can download these files and keep them in the specified folder. After that, just call `fetch_lfw_people` method and it will load the data from this location without connecting to internet.

Here `~` refers to the home location of user. You can use the following code to know the default location of that folder according to your system.

```
from sklearn.datasets import get_data_home
print(get_data_home())
```

Since you have changed that value to `data_home='.'`, so you should use the `~/lfw_home` without `'scikit_learn_data'` (i.e. Make `lfw_home` directly in the home folder).

Comment: Awesome advice, thank you! Are this link the only places I can download those datasets? Looks like it is blocked at my PC!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam These are the locations sklearn uses to download the dataset. Maybe you can find other locations too. But I am not sure how they work with sklearn code then